# Adding app feature from Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-compatibility

I want to add a new feature to my app that was introduced in ICS but I still want people with 2.x,3.x to be able to access the app because if I change the targeted API version phones below the API version wont be able to download it in the market correct?

Is my only option to create another APK? This solution brings another problem though because I dont want people who have already bought the app to have to pay for it again to get ICS compatibility, thats obviously going to make people unhappy.

so what can I do?

Comment: You can use [reflection](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html).

Comment: .... and http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [blog posting here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html) about the general problem of using newer Android features in an app that also needs to run on older platform versions. The blog is too old to address Ice Cream Sandwich in particular, but the techniques will still work well, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can publish Multiple APKs on the Market

More info here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html